# TailwindCSS masonry with specific order of elements

Tags: grid, tailwind-css

I have a grid layout with 4 elements that should have a specific place in desktop and mobile sizes and it's ok besides the masonry. the third and fourth elements are not near to each other!

see jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/amnshojaei/0krpufxa/6/

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-[24px]">
  <div class="h-[200px] col-span-full lg:col-start-1 lg:col-end-9 lg:row-start-1 lg:row-end-2">1</div>
  <div class="h-[200px] col-span-full lg:col-start-1 lg:col-end-9 lg:row-start-2 lg:row-end-3">2</div>
  <div class="h-[100px] col-span-full lg:col-start-9 lg:col-end-13 lg:row-start-1 lg:row-end-2">3</div>
  <div class="h-[100px] col-span-full lg:col-start-9 lg:col-end-13 lg:row-start-2 lg:row-end-3">4</div>
</div>
```

I want to have something like this **with auto height elements**:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Tailwind's [`columns` utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/columns) should work for your use case!